# definition of indiscernibles

Tags: logic, model-theory

i'm confused about the definition of indiscernibles in the book Marker: Model Theory: An Introduction.

Let (I,<) be an ordered set, and let (xi : i ∈ I) be a sequence of distinct elements of M. We say that (xi : i ∈ I) is a sequence of order indiscernibles if whenever 
 i1

And, if claim from the definition holds for a fixed m and some set I, does it hold for every i

The question also goes for diagonal indiscernibles.

We say that I ⊆ M is a sequence of diagonal indiscernibles for Γ if whenever φ(u1,...,um,v1,...,vn) ∈ Γ x0,...,xn,y1,...,yn ∈ I with x0

If m and n from the definition are fixed, does the claim from the definition holds for all i

Comment: There seems to be a lot of text missing from the definitions your question. Not enough is written for me to understand what diagonal indiscernibles are. Noah answered your question that the definition holds for all $m$. But in your second and third questions, it's not clear to me what "does it hold for every $i$?" means.  Can you clarify?

Comment: i don't know how to repair it. definition is in Marker Model theory: An Introduction book, page 179. i thought it is defined just for formulas with m variables does it imply that if holds for those formulas that it holds for formulas with less variables than m. but, noah answered, that definition stands for all formulas (with any finite number of variables), but the question is still valid, hypotetically.

Comment: @Ana You've definitely copied incompletely. Look at the last sentence of your second paragraph: "We say that (xi : i ∈ I) is a sequence of order indiscernibles if whenever i1". That sentence hasn't finished! Similarly, your definition of diagonal indiscernibles isn't complete:  "with x0 . . . "

Comment: yes, i can see that, but before i post, it looks complete. when i post, some parts are missing and i don't know why. if someone knows what could be the problem, i will be greatefull for an explanation in order to post without difficulties in the future.

Comment: @Ana Have you tried typing the quote by hand? That's one foolproof way to do this . . .

Comment: @Noah, i don't know how to write math text in this editor.

Comment: @Ana See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Basically, put dollar signs around mathematical content, underscores for subscripts, and \phi, etc. for Greek letters.

Comment: @Noah, thank you, i'll have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indiscernibility is for *all* formulas in *all* arities (although one can speak of restricted forms of indiscernibility).

---

For example, in the structure $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$, *any* (monotonic) sequence is a sequence of indiscernibles, because all the structure can "say" is whether one element is above another.

By contrast, in $(\mathbb{Z}, <)$ there are *no* indiscernible sequences. This is because we have formulas expressing "There are exactly $n$ elements between $x$ and $y$" for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and for any $a, b\in\mathbb{Z}$, exactly one of those formulas holds. So, for example, why can't $(1, 2, 3)$ be the beginnining of an indiscernible sequence? Well, let $\varphi(x, y)=\neg\exists z(x<z<y)$; then $\varphi(1, 2)$ holds but $\varphi(1, 3)$ doesn't, even though $(1, 2)$ and $(1, 3)$ are tuples "of the same type" from the point of view of the sequence $(1, 2, 3)$.

Comment: thank you noah, very much. i'm looking for examples for indiscernibles. if a language has just one relation defined for one variable R(x), is it sure that a sequence of inciscernibles in a structure for that one atomic formula R is the sequence of indiscernibles for all formulas.

if we have a language with one relational symbol R(x,y) and we interpret it on N, with R(x,y) with a meaning x and y are coprime does it hold that the set of primes with the defined order I is a sequence of indiscernibles for all formulas in the structure.

Comment: if we have a language with one relational symbol R(x,y) and we interpret it on N, with R(x,y) with a meaning x and y are coprime does it hold that the set of primes with the defined order I is a sequence of indiscernibles for all formulas in the structure. noah said, yes, but how to prove it?

Comment: @Ana The answers to both questions are yes. A brute-force way to show this would be via induction on formula complexity, which you're familiar with presumably; a better way would be via *automorphisms*. Show that if a sequence $I$ has the *automorphism property* - namely, for any tuples $\overline{a}$, $\overline{b}$ in $I$ (of the same length, and both in order), there is an automorphism of the structure sending $\overline{a}$ to $\overline{b}$ - then $I$ is a sequence of indiscernibles. (cont'd)

Comment: In particular, re: your second comment, can you show that any permutation of the primes gives rise to an automorphism of $(\mathbb{N}, R)$? (Incidentally, the sequences of indiscernibles your comments mention are actually **sets** of indiscernibles; this is a significantly stronger property - for example, $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ has no nontrivial sets of indiscernibles, even though it has lots of sequences of indiscernibles.)

Comment: do you mean automorphism whehe function is defined as a permutation on prime variables and as identity on all of the other? do all of the subsets of Q in increased order form a sequence of indiscernibles?

Comment: first: do you think of the function defined as a permutation of N, for prime variables and identity function on all of the other? second: are all subsets od Q in an increased order sequences od indiscernibles?

Comment: @Ana Re: your first question, no - such a permutation could e.g. swap $3$ and $2$ but keep $9$ fixed, and this would *not* be an automorphism. You need to think about how a permutation of the primes *induces* an automorphism of the whole structure; e.g. if we swap $3$ and $2$, what should $9$ be swapped with? Re: your second question, yes (as long as we look at sequences with the same order type!), and for sequences of length $\omega$ (that's what we usually think of as "sequences"), automorphisms can be used to prove this: any two increasing $\omega$-sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ are automorphic.

Comment: 9 should go to 8? if n is a composite number, $n=p1^k1\times pm^km$, then f(n), z is a permutation on primes, then $f(n)=z(p1)^k1\times z(pm)^km$? is that ok? and for Q, for tuple in the increased order of the same length we can find a monotonically increasing function because, geometrically, we can connect the dots?

Comment: @Ana I think you mean $4$, not $8$. And I'm not sure what the last "$m$" is there for. But that's basically right.

Comment: thank you very much. i have learned a great deal from your comments and it made me think more. m is just an index for the last potention. i've read that there are a lot more examples and structures with indiscernible sequences than with indiscernible sets (mainly because indiscerneble set do not tolerate antisymetric relations), do you know any other examples of indiscernible sequences which are mot indiscernible sets except for the ones in (Q,<)?